# Adding .keystore to .gitignore does nothing for error

Tags: android, react-native, github

There is sensitive data in my .keystore file, explained by GitGuardian. Its recommended course of action is to add .keystore to .gitignore file, which I've already done. It doesn't change anything even when deleting repos and starting from scratch.

I cannot find the actual location of the .keystore in my React Native app. I also added android/app/debug.keystore since debug.keystore is triggering the error; that also has not helped.

I even deleted debug.keystore from github (worried about that) and error is still present somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `debug.keystore` file will be pushed to the github.
That's because default `.gitignore` file includes the following lines:

```
# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore.       <-- This means all keystore files are included in GITIGNORE list.
!debug.keystore.  <-- This line means debug.keystore is not included in GITIGNORE list. 
                      So just remove this line.
```

For your project, `.gitignore` looks like:

```
# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
*.keystore.
```

Comment: oh wow, thanks! I definitely missed the !debug.keystore line, which must have been negating adding it above the line. thanks for your help!

Comment: any idea why the keystore is, by default/design, specifically not included in gitignore?